# Check asp.net textbox value against multiple if conditions

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, asp.net-2.0

I have my website built in ASP.NET 2.0 and C#. I have textbox called tbCode where a user enters a code. I am trying to check that entered value against multiple values in the code behind on a button click.

This is my mark up so far.

```
 protected void btUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    if ((this.tbcode.Text.Trim().ToUpper() != "AB12") ||(this.tbcode.Text.Trim().ToUpper() != "DE14") || (this.tbcode.Text.Trim().ToUpper() != "XW16"))
    {
        lbmessage.Text = "Invalid Promo code. Please enter again";
    }
    else if ((this.tbcode.Text.Trim().ToUpper() == "AB12") || (this.tbcode.Text.Trim().ToUpper() == "DE14") || (this.tbcode.Text.Trim().ToUpper() == "XW16"))
    {
        Order.Shipping.Cost = 0;
        this.lShipping.Text = Order.Shipping.Cost.ToString("c");
        this.lSubtotal.Text = Order.Subtotal.ToString("c");
        this.lTotal.Text = Order.TotalCost.ToString("c");
        Order.PomoCode = this.tbcode.Text.Trim().ToUpper();
        lbmessage.Text = "Promo Code Applied.";
    }
    else
    {
        this.lShipping.Text = Order.Shipping.Cost.ToString("c");
        this.lSubtotal.Text = Order.Subtotal.ToString("c");
        this.lTotal.Text = Order.TotalCost.ToString("c");

    }

}
```

when i hit the button its always saying invalid code. not sure where am i making the mistake. It works perfectly if I am checking against just one value rather than the 3.

Thanks and appreciate it

Comment: I'm sure one of these answered your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is likely what you wanted to do:

```
protected void btUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string tbcodeValue = this.tbcode.Text.Trim().ToUpper();

    string[] validCodes = new string[] { "AB12", "DE14", "XW16" };
    if (!validCodes.Contains(tbcodeValue))
    {
        lbmessage.Text = "Invalid Promo code. Please enter again";
    }
    else 
    {
        Order.Shipping.Cost = 0;
        this.lShipping.Text = Order.Shipping.Cost.ToString("c");
        this.lSubtotal.Text = Order.Subtotal.ToString("c");
        this.lTotal.Text = Order.TotalCost.ToString("c");
        Order.PomoCode = tbcodeValue;
        lbmessage.Text = "Promo Code Applied.";
    }
}
```

First off, you were calling `this.tbcode.Text.Trim().ToUpper()` all over the place.  That really clutters up your code and makes it hard to read.  Assigning that to a variable not only makes the code cleaner, but avoids performing all of those string manipulation functions over and over.

Next, it appears that your intent is to say, "if the textbox value isn't any of these values, run some code saying it's invalid.  The easiest way to do that is to put all of the valid values into a container of some sort and see if it contains the value you're interested in.  Your next block of code is basically for, "if it is one of the valid values".  So if it *does* contain the string then it is valid.  As for your else, I couldn't figure out what the intent of it was.  Either the string is invalid, or it's valid.  I don't see any third case there, so I just removed it.

Comment: Thanks for the replay but I am getting an error saying that System.Array does not contain a definition for contains

Comment: @niceoneishere I used the LINQ contains method.  Just add a `using` for `System.Linq`.

Comment: hmm not sure if I can do that, as mentioned in my post my website is built in ASP.NET 2.0

Comment: @niceoneishere The fundamental concept remains, even if you can't copy/paste my code and have it work for you.  You need to put the values in a data structure and then determine if the value that you want is in that data structure.  You have all sorts of options.  You could use a different data structure that *does* have a `Contains` method, you could write your own `Contains` method, or you could find an existing library method (other than Linq) that does this (`Array` has such methods in older versions of .NET).

Comment: I used ILISTS like if (!((IList<string>)validCodes).Contains(tbcodeValue))
        {
            lbmessage.Text = "Invalid Promo code. Please enter again";
        }

Comment: @niceoneishere `List` does have a `Contains` method, yes, so you can use that.  You could just change the entire structure to a `List<string>` for simplicity.  My point here is that you shouldn't just do whatever you can to get your code to compile and execute; think critically about what you're doing, what the approach is, and why you're choosing to do everything that you're doing.

Comment: What you mean? I am not talking about list string , in ASP.NET 2.0 does not contain definition for system.array which I wanted to use in the first place for less clutter. but your idea made me remember that we can use contains in ASP.NET 2.0 as its a part of Generic.IList.

Comment: I do appreciate your concern but I am very much aware in what I am doing Sir. Thanks and appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your ||'s to &&'s in the first if statement.  You are always going to fall into that block otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 if ((this.tbcode.Text.Trim().ToUpper() != "AB12") && (this.tbcode.Text.Trim().ToUpper() != "DE14") && (this.tbcode.Text.Trim().ToUpper() != "XW16"))
    {
        lbmessage.Text = "Invalid Promo code. Please enter again";
    }
    else if ((this.tbcode.Text.Trim().ToUpper() == "AB12") || (this.tbcode.Text.Trim().ToUpper() == "DE14") || (this.tbcode.Text.Trim().ToUpper() == "XW16"))
    {
        Order.Shipping.Cost = 0;
        this.lShipping.Text = Order.Shipping.Cost.ToString("c");
        this.lSubtotal.Text = Order.Subtotal.ToString("c");
        this.lTotal.Text = Order.TotalCost.ToString("c");
        Order.PomoCode = this.tbcode.Text.Trim().ToUpper();
        lbmessage.Text = "Promo Code Applied.";
    }
    else
    {
        this.lShipping.Text = Order.Shipping.Cost.ToString("c");
        this.lSubtotal.Text = Order.Subtotal.ToString("c");
        this.lTotal.Text = Order.TotalCost.ToString("c");

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also employ a switch;case; block.

```
String testtext = this.tbcode.Text.Trim().ToUpper();

switch(testtext)
{
    case "AB12":
        // Do stuff for this case
        break;
    case "Text2":
        // Do stuff for this case
        break;
    default:
        // anything that fails all above tests goes here
        break;
}
```

Just be sure to either break, return, or continue after each case or you will get a compile error. Also default needs to be last in line.